# How to protect a stored procedure file from reading - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, encryption

I want to generate a file that contains a stored procedure query and I want to share it, but I need to protect it from reading. This query will be used by another person in his own database and server.

I want to give a SP to another person to use in a different environment but doesn't want them to be able to read the TSQL in the SP.

How can I do that?

Comment: What do you mean by protect it from reading? Are you wanting to protect your query from being visible by somebody else? If that is the case the ONLY way is to keep the query on your server and expose the data via a service or some other remote method.

Comment: I want to share it,<> I need to protect it from reading

Comment: Take a look at any number of introductions to basic cryptography such as [PGP](http://www.pgpi.org/doc/pgpintro/). Your question is too broad to supply an answer beyond pointing you in a general direction.

Comment: Do I understand this as meaning that you want anyone to have execute permissions, but not read or write permissions?

Comment: @GordonLinoff i think the OP wants to give a SP to another person to use in a different environment but doesn't want them to be able to actually read the TSQL in the SP. i.e. protect his source code. Maybe i'm wrong?

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with SQL really.  I think he has a file (that happens to be a proc definition) that he want to pass to someone else for them to use on their own system. Why this would need to be encrypted I don't know, but I think that is what the OP is wanting to do and that is what the question is about. The mystery to me is if he doesn't even want the recipient to be able to read it (ha) or if he is just concerned about third parties.

Comment: @scsimon Yes, it's exactly what i need.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `WITH ENCRYPTION` clause.  However, it is known to be [ineffective and easily broken](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/353459/A-simple-hack-of-a-built-in-MS-SQL-Server-WITH-ENC), and there are third party tools available that will let your client break it.

If you want to do it anyway, a tutorial can be found [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2964/encrypting-and-decrypting-sql-server-stored-procedures-views-and-userdefined-functions/).

If you use `WITH ENCRYPTION` along with a thoughtfully constructed [EULA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-user_license_agreement), your client should not accidentally see the code, and if he purposefully goes to the trouble to crack your code encryption, you will have civil recourse (i.e. you can sue them).